# how to implement MessageBodyWriter method writeTo for json response?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jersey-2.0

How should I configure `writeTo` method so that it convert detail to json response .

```
  @Override
public void writeTo(Detail detail, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotation, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException 
{

     try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(detail.getClass());
            // serialize the entity myBean to the entity output stream
            jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(detail, entityStream);


        } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
            jaxbException.printStackTrace();
            throw new ProcessingException(
                "Error serializing a "+ detail +" to the output stream", jaxbException);
        }

}
```

Yet now I am getting `XML` response from it.

MY resource code is:

```
   @POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("testDetail")
public TestDetail testDetail()
{

    TestDetail testDetail = new TestDetail();
  return testDetail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing your own [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) for JSON? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Use one JSON provider that integrates with Jersey and it will provide you a [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) implementation. At time of writing, Jersey integrates with the following modules to provide JSON support:

- [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy)
- [Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p)
- [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)
- [Jettison](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jettison)

### Using Jackson as a JSON provider

See below the steps required to use Jackson as a JSON provider for Jersey 2.x:

**Adding Jackson module dependencies**

To use Jackson 2.x as your JSON provider you need to add [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To use Jackson 1.x it'll look like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson1</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Registering Jackson module**

Besides adding the dependency mentioned above, you need to register [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) (or [`Jackson1Feature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson1/Jackson1Feature.html) for Jackson 1.x) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(JacksonFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

If you don't have an [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class, you can register the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor. The specific resource, provider and feature fully-qualified class names can be provided in a *comma-separated value* of [`jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES) initialization parameter.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) provided by Jackson is [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html).

---

For more details, check the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html) about support for common media type representations.

Comment: BUt I want to add this in messagebodywriter , I have requirement for it.

Comment: I want to change something in the response, THis is my requirement

Comment: Providing alternatives is good, yet for all of those **actually** trying to implement a `MessageBodyWriter` this "answer" is not an answer to the actual question

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to be writing your own serialization code. You are probably missing the `jersey-media-json-jackson` artifact dependency. Look through [this example](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson).

Comment: I already have register(Jackson1Feature.class); code in my resourceconfig file

Comment: Why was this down voted? @cássio-mazzochi-molin literally said the same thing I did, but with more details.