# how to fetch anotations values in writeTo method of MessageBodyWriter in jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am overriding `MessageBodyWriter`'s  `WriteTo` method:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(Detail detail, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotation, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
}
```

There is an `annotation` parameter. Actually I want to fetch `view` annotation from this, so that I can return `Detail` data according to  `view`.

Here is my `WriteTo` code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
mapper.writerWithView(JSONView.CustomerView.class).writeValue(entityStream, detail);
```

Actually, I want to fetch view name from the annotation, so that I can return specific data according to view.

**How can I fetch `view` class name from anotation ?**

Here is my resource code:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("testDetail")
@JsonView(JSONView.TicketView.class)
public TestDetail testDetail()
{
    TestDetail testDetail = new TestDetail();
    return testDetail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are particularly interested in getting resource methods annotations in you custom implementation of [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html). But *you don't need to do that for the purpose you've mentioned in your question*.

The Jackson module for JAX-RS provides this feature out-of-the-box and you won't need to code it by yourself. Quoting the [project page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers):

> In addition to annotation value classes, it is also possible to use a subset of Jackson annotations with provider.
>   Here is a short list of supported annotations that work with all formats:
>
> - `@JsonView` can be used to define active view for specific endpoint
>
> [...]

The [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.2/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) artifact has a dependency to the `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` artifact, which provides you such feature. So, just configure Jackson as your JSON provider (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874137/1426227) for more details) and the support for [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) will be provided out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hello , I want to do so. I have requirement for it. :-) please suggest some thing

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```
JsonView jsonView = this.getClass().getAnnotation(JsonView.class);
```

or

```
JsonView jsonView = TestDetail.class.getAnnotation(JsonView.class);
```

for method you use:

```
Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("testDetail"); (or this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testDetail"))
JsonView type = method.getAnnotation(JsonView.class);
```

and after just do:

```
type.value()
```

Comment: Sorry you want for the method, I'll update the code.

Comment: In which package Method is ??

Comment: @PrashantSharma this is reflection so java.lang.reflect.Method. You just have to check the return type.